# r - split one csv file into multiple txt files

Tags: r, split, csv

I need to split one large .csv file, with about 9 columns and more than 9,000 rows, into a separate .txt file for each row, and name each newly generated file by the name in its first column.

e.g.
for the .csv file:

```
01001_r1    32.4327 -86.6190    0.65    0.20    0.15    1.33    5.47    8
01001_r2    32.4327 -86.6190    0.65    0.20    0.15    1.33    5.46    8
01001_r3    32.4327 -86.6190    0.80    0.15    0.05    1.33    5.23    10
01003_r1    30.4887 -87.6918    0.65    0.20    0.15    1.33    5.23    9
01003_r2    30.4887 -87.6918    0.80    0.15    0.05    1.33    5.25    9
01003_r3    30.4887 -87.6918    0.65    0.20    0.15    1.33    4.96    8
```

I would end up with 6 files, with one row each.

Columns in the output file need to be 'tab separated', and the file must not contain neither row or column names.

e.g the output files should look like this:

```
01001_r1    32.4327 -86.6190    0.65    0.20    0.15    1.33    5.47    8
```

This is where I've gotten this far:

```
#set 'working directory'
setwd('C:/Users/Data/soils_data/sitesoil_in')

#identify data frame from .csv file
sd <- read.csv('site_soil.csv', sep="\t", header=F, fill=F)

lapply(1:nrow(sd), function(i) write.csv(sd[i,],
                                         file = paste0(sd[i,1], ".txt"),
                                         row.names = F, header = F,
                                         quote = F))
```

And this is what I get for each output file:

file name: 01001_r1

```
V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9
01001_r1,32.4327,-86.619,0.65,0.2,0.15,1.33,5.47,8
```

I can't get it to eliminate the columns names or to separate the columns with tabs.
I have tried with header = F, or col.names = F to eliminate headings, and sep = "\t" to separate the columns but it does not recognize the commands.

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks,
E.

Following all suggestions, this is the simpler code that would do the trick:

```
#set 'working directory'
setwd('C:/Users/Elena/Desktop/DayCent_muvp_MODEL/DayCent_SourceData/soils_data/sitesoil_in')

#identify data frame from .csv file
sd <- read.csv('site_soil.csv', sep="\t", header=F, fill=F)

lapply(1:nrow(sd), 
       function(i) write.table(sd[i,],
                               file = paste0(sd[i,1], ".txt",collapse = ""),
                               row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE,
                               sep = "\t"
       ))
```

Thank you all for your help.
E.

Comment: check write.table - Your approach saves it again as .csv which is not desirable in your case. Could you explain the intention behind this merely useful split into thousands of .txt files littering your disk?

Comment: Thank you Christian, I've tried that, but it gives me an error if I use write.table instead of write.csv ... These are input files for another code generating files for a model input. The later code requires these files to be in a very specific format to recognize the information.

Comment: You will want to investigate the error being given then. `write.csv` is a wrapper around `write.table`, as described by the docs (`?write.table`), and is not intended to be as flexible. In my experience it is almost always better to use `write.table` and manually specify the correct arguments needed, rather than use `write.csv` and hope that its args are the ones you need.

Comment: Thank you user5359531,I'll check the arguments as you suggest, see if I can find the source of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted your code:

```
lapply(1:nrow(sd),
    function(i) write.table(sd[i,],
                            file = paste0(sd[i,1],".txt",collapse = ""),
                            row.names = FALSE,
                            sep = "\t"
                            ))
```

Comment: It works! thanks!! why wouldn't it recognize write.table before? Now I just need to figure out how to eliminate the column names. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
dat <-"01001_r1,32.4327,-86.6190,0.65,0.20,0.15,1.33,5.47,8
01001_r2,32.4327,-86.6190,0.65,0.20,0.15,1.33,5.46,8
01001_r3,32.4327,-86.6190,0.80,0.15,0.05,1.33,5.23,10
01003_r1,30.4887,-87.6918,0.65,0.20,0.15,1.33,5.23,9
01003_r2,30.4887,-87.6918,0.80,0.15,0.05,1.33,5.25,9
01003_r3,30.4887,-87.6918,0.65,0.20,0.15,1.33,4.96,8
"


df <- read.delim(file = textConnection(dat), sep = ',', header = FALSE)

df
#         V1      V2       V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8 V9
# 1 01001_r1 32.4327 -86.6190 0.65 0.20 0.15 1.33 5.47  8
# 2 01001_r2 32.4327 -86.6190 0.65 0.20 0.15 1.33 5.46  8
# 3 01001_r3 32.4327 -86.6190 0.80 0.15 0.05 1.33 5.23 10
# 4 01003_r1 30.4887 -87.6918 0.65 0.20 0.15 1.33 5.23  9
# 5 01003_r2 30.4887 -87.6918 0.80 0.15 0.05 1.33 5.25  9
# 6 01003_r3 30.4887 -87.6918 0.65 0.20 0.15 1.33 4.96  8

output_file_base <- "soil_"
output_file_ext <- ".tsv"

for(i in seq(nrow(df))){
    output_file <- paste0(output_file_base, as.character(i), output_file_ext)
    dfi <- df[i, ]
    write.table(x = dfi, file = output_file, sep = '\t', quote = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Output:

```
$ cat soil_6.tsv
01003_r3    30.4887 -87.6918    0.65    0.2 0.15    1.33    4.96    8
```

Comment: Thanks again. I tried converting to df, and it works great for limited data. The problem is that with more than 9,000 rows I end up with a 8,000-line code... I was trying to find a simpler solution...

Comment: I was missing a comma for the col.names argument! funny that. I realized reviewing your code, thanks again for your help.

Comment: "The problem is that with more than 9,000 rows I end up with a 8,000-line code." Not sure what you mean by this, I hope you're not embedding the entire CSV file contents in your script? Your original post shows you are reading the CSV into a df directly. I am not clear what other lines of code you need beyond this.

Comment: Sorry @user5359531, I misunderstood your answer. I see what you mean. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This may work for what you are trying to accomplish.

```
df  <-read.csv(text = "01001_r1,32.4327,-86.6190,0.65,0.20,0.15,1.33,5.47,8
01001_r2,32.4327,-86.6190,0.65,0.20,0.15,1.33,5.46,8
01001_r3,32.4327,-86.6190,0.80,0.15,0.05,1.33,5.23,10
01003_r1,30.4887,-87.6918,0.65,0.20,0.15,1.33,5.23,9
01003_r2,30.4887,-87.6918,0.80,0.15,0.05,1.33,5.25,9
01003_r3,30.4887,-87.6918,0.65,0.20,0.15,1.33,4.96,8",
stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
header = FALSE)


apply(df, 1, function(x){write.table(t(x), 
                                     file = paste0(x[1],".txt"), 
                                     sep = "\t", 
                                     quote = FALSE, 
                                     col.names = FALSE, 
                                     row.names = FALSE)})
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. I tried converting to df, and it works great for limited data. The problem is that with more than 9,000 rows I end up with a 8,000-line code... I was trying to find a simpler solution... In any case, I'll keep your code for later use, thanks again!

Comment: It has been a while since this post, but how could you modify this code for a chunk instead of a single row? ie, 20 rows?

Comment: I would probably split the dataframe into a list of 20 row data frames `ldf <- split(df, (as.numeric(rownames(df))-1) %/% 20)` Then use a lapply function on the list to write each of those data frames to it's own file. `lapply(ldf, function(x){write.table(x, file = paste0("Rows ", min(rownames(x)), " - ", max(rownames(x)),".txt"), sep = "\t", quote = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)})`